# Android web view (browser) inside spinner?

Tags: java, android, webview, spinner

I want to add website (browser) inside spinner like when I choose Google from list I go to www.google.com? And I don't know the right code for this? ................

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.social);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();

    categories.add("Google");

    categories.add("Facebook");

    categories.add("Yahoo");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}


@Override

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call :

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("www."+item+".com"));
    startActivity(i);
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
{}
```